# Text does not update in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm designing a game for my project and somehow the score(text) does not update after an action. It stuck at 0.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class uiManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Text scoreText;
bool gameOver;
int score;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    gameOver = false;
    score = 0;
    InvokeRepeating ("scoreUpdate", 1.0f, 0.5f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    scoreText.text = "Point: " + score;
}

void scoreUpdate()
{
    if (gameOver == false) 
    {
        score += 1;
    }
}

public void gameOVER()
{
    gameOver = true;
}

public void Play()
{
    Application.LoadLevel ("MuachiJump");
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "branch")
    {
        score += 1;
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I just want to make sure is there any mistake in this code? All of them seem to be correct.

Comment: Side note, you should not print your score in the update as you are. It creates a new string and discard the previous one each frame. Instead, use a property on your score member that also updates the text. This way it only creates a new string when you change the value.

Answer (score 3):

The code by itself seems fine.  Make sure that `uiManager` is attached to an object in your scene that is active.  In the `Update` method, if you add, for example, `Debug.Log(score)`, it should print to the log every frame.  If this isn't happening, you need to attach the script to an object in your scene as well as make sure that the Text object has a valid reference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an active object with the script attached on your scene?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the size of the textbox was the issue, just enlarge it and your score will be visible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31062195)